# How do I display cin answer in my program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

```
cout <<"\n\nYour name ?:" ;

cin >> name;

getline(cin,name);

cout <<"Hello"<<name;
```

Comment: store it in some variable and cout the variable...

Comment: i put name in string butit doesn't work

Comment: Ideal use-case for debugger. Step through the code and watch variables. You'll find a mistake quickly.

Comment: You're reading twice - first with `>>`, then with `getline` - and storing the result in the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
//declaring header mains
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Method: The main method
//Purpose: To get the users name, age, and money; and return the information
//Parameters: Name as string, age as integer, and money as a float value
//Returns: Users inputted name, age, and money
int main()
{
    //Declaring variables
    string fullName;
    int age;
    float money;

    //Promt the user to enter their age
    cout << "\nPlease enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;

    //Prompt the user to enter their amount of money
    cout << "\nPlease tell me how much money you have: ";
    cin >> money;

    //Prompt the user to enter their full name
    cout << "\nPlease enter your full name: ";
    getline( cin, fullName);

    //Display the name back to the user; and adds another line
    cout << "\n" << fullName << endl;

    //Display the age back to the user
    cout << "\nYou are " << age;  
    cout << " years old; ";

    //Display the amount of money back to the user
    cout << "\nand you have $" << money;
    cout << " in your pocket.";

    //Giving the user an ending message
    cout << "\nGoodbye .....\n";

    //Keeping the window open
    system("PAUSE");

    // and finally, return zero
    return 0;
}
```

Output is -->

```
Please enter your age: 12
Please tell me how much money you have: 10
Please enter your full name: ABC XYZ
ABC XYZ
You are 12 years old;
and you have $10 in your pocket.
Goodbye .....
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: i did the same thing but it doesnt work with the name im trying to display at the end of my program

Comment: i hope you have already defined the name variable. Then this is the problem of your compiler. cause same is working find on my system.

Comment: yes i put name in string but it doesn't display the name only work with numbers I also tried with your code and it still doesnt show the name in cout << "\nThank you " << fullName << endl;

Comment: Dont use "cin >> name;" in your code try executing your code without it

Comment: your welcome.. please rate this answer. if its helpful to you :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please delete  `"cin >> name;"` from your code.
And Try running it without it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete getline(), you dont need cin >> name and getline, delete one of then, preferbaly the getline because the cin line is the way to get stuff in c++